# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: jquery, django

here is the html

```
<input id="fileUpload" multiple="multiple" type="file"/> 
 <ul>
 <li><div id="image-holder"></div></li>
 <li><input type="submit" value="Next"></li>
</ul>
```

here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit').click(function() {  

    var files = $("[type='file']")[0].files;

    console.log(files)

    var data = {
       'images[]' : files , 
       csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}'
      }

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : "{% url 'data_entry' %}",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {  
            },
            error: function(response, error) {
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

On submit click i get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

How can i send images using jquery to django view?

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the Jquery don't process the files. And also I found the workaround to add file in data... hope this will help...

that `Illegal invocation` error is because ajax doesn't handle objects... that's why we serialize form before entering into ajax and now your case you directly inject the file object then the error.

```
var data = new FormData();
$.each(files, function(key, value)
{
    data.append(key, value);
});
```

And in ajax...

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    processData: false,
    ....
```

Comment: what about csrf? it throws me 403 forbidden error when i dont process the data

Comment: I tested with `csrf_exempt`

Comment: isnt this a bad policy to not include csrf token.is there no other way around?

Comment: @AdityaSingh you can use `csrf_protect` on that particular view https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_protect

Comment: No it doesnt help...still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118084/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-aditya-singh).